# Add AfterBuild target on multiple projects in a solution

Tags: msbuild, dynamics-crm-2011, ilmerge

I use ILMerge to merge all binaries in to one due to an MS Dynamics limitation.

It use to be a manual process specifying all the binaries to merge but I found this article to automatically find the dependencies for a project and merge them in to the assembly using the AfterBuild target - [instructions here](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/leveraging-ilmerge-to-simplify-deployment-and-your-users-experience/).

The downside here is that I need to edit the csproj file and add the [`<import>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) element in for every project I want to ILMerge. Is there a way I can do it for every project in a solution (preferably every project in a solution folder)?

Answer (score 0):

The project files are just XML.  There is nothing stopping you from creating your own file editor utility to search for and inject your desired xml elements into the project file.